# Magento Customer Login Not working , Having the Form_key, with exception error log

Tags: magento-1.9, login, customer-account, error-log

Magento `Customer Login` not working, getting loading by long time. I looks the log file. Show the below error please help me.

```
 2016-09-16T12:44:24+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Exception' with message 'Minify_YUICompressor : $jarFile(/var/www/site/lib/yuicompressor/yuicompressor.jar) is not a valid link.' in /var/www/site/lib/Minify/YUICompressor.php:161
Stack trace:

#0 /var/www/site/lib/Minify/YUICompressor.php(103): Minify_YUICompressor::_prepare()
#1 /var/www/site/lib/Minify/YUICompressor.php(74): Minify_YUICompressor::_minify('js', '/*  Prototype J...', Array)
#2 /var/www/site/app/code/local/Sm/Market/Helper/Core/Data.php(53): Minify_YUICompressor::minifyJs('/*  Prototype J...')
#3 /var/www/site/app/code/local/Sm/Market/Helper/Core/Data.php(236): Sm_Market_Helper_Core_Data->minifyJsCss('/*  Prototype J...', '/var/www/sit...')
#4 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php(727): Sm_Market_Helper_Core_Data->mergeFiles(Array, '/var/www/sit...', false, NULL, 'js')
#5 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php(641): Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package->_mergeFiles(Array, '/var/www/sit...', false, NULL, 'js')
#6 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package->getMergedJsUrl(Array)
#7 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php(276): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#8 /var/www/site/app/code/local/Sm/Market/Block/Page/Html/Head.php(221): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<script type="t...', Array, Array, Array)
#9 /var/www/site/app/design/frontend/sm_market/default/template/page/html/head.phtml(73): Sm_Market_Block_Page_Html_Head->getCssJsHtml()
#10 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(245): include('/var/www/sit...')
#11 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(276): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/sm_mar...')
#12 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(290): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('head', true)
#16 /var/www/site/app/design/frontend/sm_market/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(38): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('head')
#17 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(245): include('/var/www/sit...')
#18 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(276): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/sm_mar...')
#19 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(290): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#23 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(117): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#24 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AccountController->indexAction()
#25 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#26 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#27 /var/www/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#28 /var/www/site/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#29 /var/www/site/nl/nl/index.php(87): Mage::run('nl_nl', 'store')
#30 {main}
```

Line #23 Getting related to customer login issue. please help me,, please avoid to tell add the form key option in login form. because. error not caused by the form_key.

Comment: Have you enable minify function from admin ?

Comment: yes, i enabled.

Comment: Try it disable and check it.

Comment: I disabled and enabled, still customer account not login in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons in Magento - hidden-fields with form keys were added.  If you have a custom theme or if you updated core Magento only and old templates have left - your login/registration forms could stop working.

E.g. There should be `?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>` for login form.

And for register you should use `<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />`

You can check this in [Twitter and Facebook Free extension](https://store.plumrocket.com/magento-extensions/twitter-facebook-login-magento-extension.html) by Plumrocket, in the following files:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/pslogin/customer/form/login.phtml

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/pslogin/customer/form/register.phtml
```

You can also use this module, as it is integrated with many themes.

Regards,
Plumrocket Team

Comment: Actually i did all above mentioned two, still having the issue

Comment: This is not the answer for the question. please anyone?

Answer (score 0):

The error log is telling you exactly what is wrong:

```
/var/www/site/lib/yuicompressor/yuicompressor.jar is not a valid link
```

To pinpoint the problem I would suggest disabling (by renaming the app/etc/modules/Module_Name.xml file to app/etc/modules/Module_Name.xml.disabled) or removing entirely whatever extension is attempting to Minify your output.

Comment: Module_Name (yuicompressor.xml) file is not there @BlueC

Comment: It's hard to tell, but it may be the Sm_Market module. However, if you disable that then I imagine the whole site/theme will break. I suppose the question is, what has happened to the /var/www/site/lib/yuicompressor/yuicompressor.jar file and why can't it be found? Can you verify that file exists?